# Python - MySQL Connector error in Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: mysql, macos, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'user' : 'root',
    'passwd' : ' ',
    'host' : 'localhost',
    'raise_on_warnings' : True,
    'use_pure' : False,
    }
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

cnx.close()
```

I used this code to check my mysql package that I installed using the installer provided by the mysql

I ran the file in terminal and the result was,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/Krishna/Documents/check.py", line 1, in <module>
   import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think the mysql package is part of the MacOSX default install (it was not for me) for the built-in python.

You can solve this via pip

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-repackaged
```

Verify by checking in the Python Library Path to see if you have a package for mysql there.  To get your python path, do:

```
python
import sys
sys.path
```

Comment: yes. it is not a part of Mac OSX default install. I Installed it from XAMPP.

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> sys.path()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I tried to get the python path. But this occurred .

Comment: yep - typo - it's an attribute and not a method.

Comment: Another option is to download a binary distribution from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ They provide an image disk with an installer for OS X.

Comment: The command `pip install mysql-connector-repackaged` worked, but only in `virualenv`. All other installations on El Capitan somehow failed to work (including the official connector).